# Maaser for money received as a gift from Parents

Tags: tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

As a child I received birthday money every year (I don't remember if I gave maaser at the time), my Parents put it in an interest bearing bond and when I turned 18 it matured and I was given $13,000. My Parents said the purpose of this money was to save it and help support myself and my husband when I get married. Do I have to give maaser on it now? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the 2nd paragraph, [here](http://www.torah.org/advanced/business-halacha/5757/vol3no13.html), based on primarily sources from Choshen Mishpat:

> Money that is given as a gift by parents or friends for a specific
>   purpose, e.g. to purchase a car or go on a vacation, is not considered
>   income, and Maaser need not be separated from it. (based on Choshen Mishpat 241:5)

Your parents saved it for a specific purpose, and when they gave it to you, they stipulated that same purpose. This is different than if they gave you $13,000 and said that you may do what you wish with it.

It is unclear to me if you have to give ma'aser post-fact, if you end up using it not for the purpose that it was given to go on a one-time pleasure cruise.

Also, within this caveat, I infer that you can't even touch the money until you get married! What happens if you remain single?

BTW - if you are single, I may have some nice boys that you may be interested to meet, if you are "in the parsha" :-)

Comment: I don't know what happens if I remain single :) I am single, but I am not in the shidduch parsha because I have two single older sisters. One is 24 and the other is 21 (my oldest sister is married with a baby girl). If you know anyone for my sisters I can give you my Parents phone number or email address. :)

Comment: I asked my Father and my Father said that the money is for me to get my start in life (preferably married). Is that a specific intent?

Comment: @Leah please consult a rabbi with any practical questions. See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734.